# Should my program be an application or service?

Tags: windows

I am writing a program to automatically sync databases every 15 minutes. The flow will be from changes in Database A sync-ed to Database B, followed by changes in Database B sync-ed to Database A. The program will then sleep for 15 minutes and continue the sync changes based on the previous successful timestamp. Thus, it need to store the timestamp of sync. My program will be creating logs and stores the timestamp.

It does not require any manual intervention from the user unless it hits any bad scenario and breaks the program. Considering this risk, Should I run this program as an application or service? And why?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: This should be a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't run as an app when nobody logs in.  Which is the real problem with these kind of apps, they are about as exciting as watching grass grow after you get the bugs ironed out.  So people stop paying attention or start to dislike having to babysit it.

Also a concern for errors, you may have to send an alert to another machine to wake somebody up.

Then a scheduled task becomes a viable option as well.  Which does have the advantage of the process terminating and not consuming resources while it waits idly for the next 15 minute interval to arrive.  Much easier to debug as well.  A service is better at recognizing that there's something fundamentally wrong with the dbase and stopping itself.  And giving an admin control over it.  Which usually are compelling reasons enough to consider a service.

Answer (score 0):

The service seems like appropriate choice.

The one benefit I can think of, is that you can set it as 'Automatic' that will ensure it starts up automatically every time the system is restarted.